# How to pass parameter values to OBJECTID in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I am writing a stored procedure with DB name as input parameter. I am creating some physical tables dynamically. If a table already exists then I need to delete the Table.

```
DECLARE @TargetDBName NVARCHAR(100) = 'PRD_Inventory'
DECLARE @TargetSchema NVARCHAR(100) = 'usr'
```

**Current Query**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempUserData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TempUserData
```

**Expected format:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('@TargetDBName.@TargetSchema.TempUserData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE @TargetDBName.@TargetSchema.TempUserData
```

Comment: `DROP TABLE` does not accept a variable. You would need dynamic SQL for this

Answer (score 1):

You would need to build your SQL dynamically for this. Note also when defining variables that refer to object names you should use the *sysname* type.

The following works on currently supported SQL Servers, it should also work on SQL Server 2008 but untested of course.

```
declare @TargetDBName sysname = 'PRD_Inventory',
        @TargetSchema sysname = 'usr', 
        @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = 'if exists (
  select * from ' + QuoteName(@TargetDBName) + '.sys.objects o
  join ' + QuoteName(@TargetDBName) + '.sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = o.schema_id
  where o.name = ''TempUserData'' and s.name = ''' + @TargetSchema + '''
) drop table '+ QuoteName(@TargetDBName) + '.' + QuoteName(@TargetSchema) + '.TempUserData;'

exec (@sql);
```